# File path on JSP and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

trying to put a file path in javascript. it is a pain 
\ is an escape character and it always kill the character after the backslash

what i am doing is this 
i am trying to add the file path from a jsp view object attribute

```
window.open("file"+<c:out value="${filePath}" />+fileName);
```

but if there are backslash in the end of filePath, it kills the following quotation mark

what is the most efficient workaround. do i have to change the java attribute notation (which i dont want to)  or get a script to do it ?

Comment: the js code is
window.open("file"+<c:out value="${filePath}" />+fileName);

Comment: Where does the value of `filePath` come from? I assume it's something the user submits with a form?

Comment: it is from the spring controller behind. it returns the value of filePath as \report2\cola, and the value is already escaped for html display purposes

Comment: What following quotation mark does it kill? There is no quotation marks surrounding the <c:out /> tag. So the output is window.open("file" + \report2\cola + fileName); which I don't think you want.

Comment: my case is, it the string ends with \, it makes the + before filename become escaped character

Comment: and r becomes \r, c becomes \c all are escaped

Comment: and "file/" is actually a path to a servlet that emits a generated file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` instead of `\`. The `/` works fine in Windows as well. You can use [`fn:replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) to replace it.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
window.open("file${fn:replace(filePath, '\\', '/')}" + fileName);
```

Note that I also fixed the "string concatenation". Concatenating `c:out` in Javascript style makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript encoding is required here for the reason that the c:out tag performs HTML encoding atleast for some meta characters, but not JavaScript encoding. In this case, JavaScript encoding of the output is required, since the output of the c:out tag appears in a JavaScript context.

Note: You can use [ESAPI](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=Java_EE) to perform this, via the JavaScriptCodec class. It would also protect you from XSS if possible via the filePath variable.

Answer (score 0):

seems that i am looking for this 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html

i simply put

```
<spring:message text="${filePath}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>
```

there is a javaScriptEscape escape attribute that allows me get the string in the javascript friendly form. hence i thought it simple solution